# Proper use of the Factory Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am trying to figure out the best solution for getting error messages in between my service layer and WebApi controllers.

I have a class `ModelStateDictionaryWrapper` that implements an interface `IValidationDictionary`

**ModelStateDictionaryWrapper**

```
public class ModelStateDictionaryWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{
    private readonly ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary;

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return this.modelStateDictionary.IsValid;
        }
    }

    public ModelStateDictionaryWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        Enforce.ArgumentNotNull(modelStateDictionary, "modelStateDictionary");

        this.modelStateDictionary = modelStateDictionary;
    }

    public void AddError(string key, string message)
    {
        this.modelStateDictionary.AddModelError(key, message);
    }
}
```

**IValidationDictionary**

```
public interface IValidationDictionary
{
    bool IsValid { get; }
    void AddError(string key, string message);
}
```

In my api controller, I am doing this:

```
public class CategoryController : ControllerBase<ICategoryService>
{
    private ICategoryService categoryService;


    public CategoryController(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.categoryService.ValidationDictionary =
            new ModelStateDictionaryWrapper(this.ModelState);
    }

    public IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel> Get()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<CategoryViewModel[]>(this.Service.GetCategories());
    }
}
```

The problem I have with this is I am making a new `ModelStateDictionaryWrapper` in the constructor of the service and I dont like that.

So I was thinking of changing this to take a factory like so:

```
public interface IModelStateWrapperFactory
{
   IValidationDictionary GetModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary);
}

public class ModelStateWrapperFactory : IModelStateWrapperFactory
{
    public IValidationDictionary GetModelStateWrapper(
        ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        return new ModelStateDictionaryWrapper(modelStateDictionary);
    }
}
```

And then the api controller would look like this (constructor):

```
public CategoryController(ICategoryService categoryService, 
    IModelStateWrapperFactory modelStateWrapperFactory)
    {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
        this.categoryService.ValidationDictionary =
            modelStateWrapperFactory.GetModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState);
    }
```

I think I have removed the tight coupling. Does this look like a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You have broken the dependencies between the classes, so you can mock the services during Unit Testing.

I don't know if you have used data annotations and a validation filter or not yet. If not, I would suggest you use them. More details from here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

An even better approach would be to completely remove this part out of the controller. It should be moved out of the controller, because:

- This is effectively a cross-cutting concern and your controller should not be concerned with it; you are violating the Single Responsibility Principle.
- Most (if not all) of your controllers will need this construct, which means that you have to repeat it all over the place, making it easy to forget it at some places; you are violating the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle.
- This construct is only possible in the case that the class that needs validation is directly injected into the controller, which might not always be the case. Sometimes you'll need to do validation deeper down the object graph, or you might want to wrap the service with a decorator or interceptor, rendering this approach useless -or at least- extremely troublesome.

There are several solutions to this approach. The first that comes to my mind is to move the setting of the `ModelState` up, out of the `CategoryController`'s constructor, for instance:

```
public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, 
    HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor, Type type)
{
    var wrapper = new ModelStateDictionaryWrapper();

    var controller = new CategoryController(new CategoryService(wrapper));

    wrapper.ModelState = controller.ModelState;

    return controller;
}
```

Another -completely different- approach is to to not use the `ModelState` property at all, but to let your business layer throw specific validation exceptions and catch them higher up the call stack and transform them to Web API status codes.

Throwing exceptions would be a much better approach for the business layer, since this prevents validation errors to go unnoticed. Besides, a design where you fill a dictionary with validation errors is related to Web API and MVC, and is not something that your business layer should be concerned with.

You can do the following in your controller when your BL throws validation exceptions:

```
public class CategoryController : ControllerBase<ICategoryService>
{
    private ICategoryService categoryService;

    public CategoryController(ICategoryService categoryService)
    {
        this.categoryService = categoryService;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Update(CategoryViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            this.categoryService.Update(model.Category);
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            return WebApiValidationHelper.ToResponseCode(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Downside here is of course that your try-catch statements with the calls to the `WebApiValidationHelper.ToResponseCode` will be duplicated in all your controllers; you'll be violating DRY.

So what you can do instead is extract this code into an `DelegatingHandler`. My preference would always be to use decorators, but unfortunately Web API makes it impossible to decorate ApiControllers, [due to a quirk in its design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444059/decorating-asp-net-web-api-ihttpcontroller). So you can inject the following `DelegatingHandler` into the Web API pipeline:

```
public class ValidationDelegationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            return WebApiValidationHelper.ToResponseCode(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This handler can be injected as follows:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ValidationDelegationHandler());
```