# Applying Dependency Injection when base-class constructor contains arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I have a base API controller that I want all controllers to execute on request, to act as a security mechanism. Here is that controller

```
public abstract class SharepointAuthController : ApiController
{
    private ClientContext clientContext;
    public SharepointAuthController()
 : base()
    {
        ValidateContext();
    }

    protected void ValidateContext()
    {
        if (ControllerContext.Request != null)
        {
            var spContext = SharePointApiControllerContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(ControllerContext);

            clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost();

            if (clientContext == null)
            {
                throw new AuthenticationException();
            }

        }
    }
    protected string GetUserName()
    {
        User spUser = null;
        var spContext = SharePointApiControllerContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(ControllerContext);
        using (clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
                clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                return spUser.Email;
            }
        }
        throw new AuthenticationException();
    }
}
```

And a controller that calls it

```
    public class CallPointsController : SharepointAuthController
{
    private readonly ICallPointRepository _callPointRepository;

    public CallPointsController(ICallPointRepository callPointRepository)
    {
        _callPointRepository = callPointRepository;
    }

    [SharePointContextFilter]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/callpoints")]
    public List<CallPointDto> Get()
    {
        string user = base.GetUserName();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            return _callPointRepository.ListAll();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I now want to extend the SharepointAuthController to get additional information about the user (exists in DB). I want to be able to pass repository into the base class's constructor for proper DI, something like so

```
  private ClientContext clientContext;
  private _repo Repo;
public SharepointAuthController(Repo repo)
: base()
{
    ValidateContext();
    _repo = repo;
}



protected UserDto GetUserName()
{
    User spUser = null;
    var spContext = SharePointApiControllerContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(ControllerContext);
    using (clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
    {
        if (clientContext != null)
        {
            spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
            clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            return _repo.GetAdditionalUserInfo(spUser.Email);
        }
    }
    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

However just doing this does not work, because the class that calls into this baseclass is not setup correctly

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the
> required formal parameter 'repo' of Repo

Am I going about this the right way? I could just call into Repo class from the Auth controller without DI

Comment: Where do you get that error?  You need to pass the parameter.

Comment: I get it in CallPointController on the constructor.

Comment: So pass the parameter.

Comment: Where exactly? There is no call to SharepointController in the CallPointController, just the inheritance.

Comment: Yes; when you inherit a class, you need to call its constructor (`: base()`)

Comment: ah got it.... i feel dumb now

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

You need to inject the parameter into your inherited class and pass it on to the parent:

```
public class SharepointAuthController
{
    public SharepointAuthController(Repo repo)
    {
        ValidateContext();
        _repo = repo;
    }
    // rest of controller ...
}

public class CallPointsController : SharepointAuthController
{
    private readonly ICallPointRepository _callPointRepository;

    public CallPointsController(ICallPointRepository callPointRepository, Repo repo) 
     : base(repo)
    {
        _callPointRepository = callPointRepository;
    }
}
```

On a different note: To do authentication, it's best not to use a base controller. Rather create an attribute (eg: `SharepointAuthAttribute`) that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute` and do the authentication in there.

Then, you can apply that attribute to the controllers that need it.

Comment: thanks for this. If I want to use a filter, can I call methods (like getuser) on the filter, or do I need to do it in each controller

Comment: You can't do that on the filter, but I believe there's a way to pass that info into the IPrincipal. I don't know exactly how though without going through the docs

Comment: Got it. So SharepointAuthController actually has a filter on it. My thought would be is that the sharepoint auth is done by the filter and the extra calls I need would be in the base

Answer (score 2):

The use of base classes is discouraged in general. The common saying is:

> [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Base classes are typically a bad idea, because:

- They result in an extra dependency on a concrete class and with that introduces strong coupling, while DI promotes loose coupling.
- This strong coupling makes your concrete controllers much harder to test, which is exaggerates in your case because you force business logic to be called inside your constructor, while [injection constructors should be simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).
- When base classes are used for cross-cutting concerns (as is in your case), they start to become a magnet for more and more cross-cutting concerns. This causes the base class to become this ever changing class that violates both the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).
- These base classes tend to require dependencies of their own. This is problematic because it easily pulls you into the [Temporal Coupling code smell](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) or the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). When you apply dependencies through the base class's constructor, the constructors of your derived classes require those dependencies as well. This means that every time you change or add a dependency to the base class, it causes sweeping changes throughout the application, because every derived class needs to be changed as well. To mitigate this, your options are to revert to property injection (which causes Temporal Coupling) or revert to the Service Locator anti-pattern. Both styles have serious downsides.

So instead of using base classes, composition is a much better way of designing your system and especially a much better way to apply cross-cutting concerns such as security.

A typical way of applying cross-cutting concerns is by the use of decorators. Web API however makes it impossible to wrap controller types with decorators. With Web API, the [designed pattern for applying cross-cutting concerns on the controller level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444059/decorating-asp-net-web-api-ihttpcontroller) is the use of `DelegatingHandler`s.

Comment: Thanks for the articles to read. So what you propose is put the logic to validate the sharepoint context AND the DB call to get additional info in their own Handlers? So whenever the api is called, it fires these handlers. At what point do I get the data I need from them?

Comment: @IsaacLevin: What do you mean by "At what point do I get the data I need from them"? Which data? Handlers get the request message that allows you to access all request data.

Comment: Well I need to make a DB call, as well as authenticate the user against Sharepoint. I need to get the return of that DB call to my controller.

Comment: @IsaacLevin: extract the logic into a service that is used in both your handler and the controller. If querying the database twice for the same information causes performance problems, add a caching decorator around this new service that caches that information for the duration of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You've added a parameter to the base class' constructor:

```
public SharepointAuthController(Repo repo)
 : base()
{
    //...
}
```

But you don't supply that parameter in the derived class' constructor:

```
public CallPointsController(ICallPointRepository callPointRepository)
{
    //...
}
```

It needs to be supplied:

```
public CallPointsController(ICallPointRepository callPointRepository, Repo repo)
 : base(repo)
{
    //...
}
```

Otherwise the derived class would have no way of constructing the base class, and therefore can't be an instance of the base class.